# Need to get true/false for each row that exists in table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql-9.4

Need to  get true/false for each row that exists in table.

My exact question how can we use EXISTS with IN clause.

For Example:
 Select exists(select 1 from table_name where table_column in ('xyz','abc')).

This returns TRUE even if one of the rows exists. I need a column that says TRUE if a row exists and FALSE if it does not. Just the status of values specified in 'IN' operator exclusively.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

### exists

FALSE  //xyz doesn't exist in table

TRUE   //abc exists in table

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    'xyz' AS item,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE table_column = 'xyz')
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS `exists`
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'abc',
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE table_column = 'abc')
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM dual;
```

Comment: But this gives complete number of rows, I need to have the boolean column consisting of the status of those two rows we used in IN clause and also even if we remove *, it still gives the boolean column but for all the rows in table. Btw thanks for the answer helps me to work on CASE now. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivaSagar Edit your question and show your _exact_ expected output.  Do not describe it in text.

Comment: Done.@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Try my updated query; just drop your current `EXISTS` clause into a `CASE` expression.

Comment: It's giving **one TRUE** if either of two values exist and **one FALSE** if none of them exists in table

Comment: @ShivaSagar I updated again.  Not sure what you really want here.

Answer (score 0):

You could compose a select with the elements you want to output ('abc' and 'xyz') using DUAL and UNION. At this point, you can do a left outer join between your previous select and the actual table. If one element is missing in the table, the attribute t.table_column will be NULL (because of the outer join) on your result set. You can then test the value using a case expression, so you will get your answer for each element.

Your query would probably look like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.table_column,
                CASE WHEN t.table_column IS NULL
                     THEN 'FALSE'
                     ELSE 'TRUE' END
                AS exist_column
  FROM (SELECT 'xyz' AS table_column FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'abc' FROM DUAL) a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
    ON t.table_column = a.table_column
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, will return one result, TRUE or FALSE

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0,TRUE,FALSE) as `Exists`
 FROM table_name
WHERE table_column in ('xyz','abc')
;
```